# finding widgets in a canvas by their handles

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to find some rectangles that I placed on a canvas, by their handles. For example, if I have 5 rectangles places in a series and their handles range from 25 to 30, I want to find the rectangles by their handles and delete the rectangles.

So far , I have seen methods which use tags to find the rectangle (or item on canvas), but tags do not work for me because I placed all of my rectangles in a loop and only the last tag seems to have been associated with a rectangle. And since I can use handles like tags to uniquely identify the rectangles, I was wondering if I can find them all given a range?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't know why you can't use tags.  Actually tags is more convenience as it can refer to a group of items which is what you need.

Comment: ***given a range?***: [Edit] your question and explain in more detail? Read up on [Tkinter.Canvas.find_*-method's](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.find_closest-method)

Answer (score 1):

`tkinter Canvas` is not fully OOP, that is you cannot, out of the box, call methods on canvas items directly on the item; you must call methods on the canvas object that will find the item, and modify its attributes. This is done with the item id, or with tags.

However, you can create a layer of OOP that will allow for the behavior you are looking for: In the following example, the `class CanvasObject` wraps canvas items in an object that can be called. You will have to wrap the canvas methods that you wish to call, in order to enable the full behavior.

The example shows how to do this with the `Canvas.itemconfig` method.

```
import tkinter as tk


class CanvasObject:
    id = 0
    def __init__(self, canvas, canvas_id):
        self.canvas = canvas          # keep a reference of the canvas
        self.canvas_id = canvas_id    # keep a reference of the item id on the canvas
        self.id = CanvasObject.id            # each CanvasObject has its own unique id
        CanvasObject.id += 1
        
    def itemconfig(self, **kwargs):
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.canvas_id, kwargs)

        
root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

# create a CanvasObject from the canvas item
rec = CanvasObject(canvas, canvas.create_rectangle((10, 10), (50, 40), fill='', outline='black'))

# dot notation call is now possible directly on the CanvasObject
rec.itemconfig(fill='red', outline='blue')   

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

> And since I can use handles like tags to uniquely identify the rectangles ...

That is not true. If you have the handle to the canvas items then you don't need to find them. You can use the handles directly, assuming by "handles" you mean the unique identifier returned when you create an item.

Here's a contrived example that creates 100 rectangles in random colors. It saves the handles for all of the green items, and presents a button that will delete the green items when clicked.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400, bg="black")
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
green_items = []
for i in range(100):
    x = random.randint(10, 390)
    y = random.randint(10, 390)
    fill = random.choice(["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"])
    item_id = canvas.create_rectangle(x,y, x+10, y+10, fill=fill)
    if fill == "green":
        green_items.append(item_id)

def delete_green():
    for item_id in green_items:
        canvas.delete(item_id)

button = tk.Button(root, text="Delete Green", command=delete_green)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, this seems like a much easier way to do it. To clarify what I meant: each item on a canvas has a unique item handle which is an integer value, so if I have like 20 items, the handles range from 1 to 20. But if I want to particularly delete a group of them, one way I could do it was to provide a separate tag like so: canvas.itemconfig(item, tags="del") in a loop , and then use this tag to find them and delete them.

Comment: @rkm19: if you have the handle, there's no need to loop over them, add a tag, and then delete, when you can just loop over them and delete. But yes, you could loop over them and add a tag. You then don't need to use the tag to "find them", just use the tag in a single delete command.